# AngularJS $http.get print 2 times in console why?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I have one example with http-get for example:

In my app:

```
function Read() {
    return $http.get(server + '/user').then(handleSuccess, handleError('Error read user'));
}
```

In my controller

```
   initController();

   function initController() {
        loadCurrentUser();
   }

function loadCurrentUser() {
    UserService.Read()
        .then(function(user) {
            vm.user = user;
            console.log(user);
        });
}
```

when i use the console.log i always receive 2 times the value

[Example of my print console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDstp.png)

Anyone know why i receive 2 times de same value? I use de ngRoute i am thinking Which is because of this.

Comment: are you sure is it consoling same line in same js ??

Comment: Check to how many View you have assigned this very same Controller. The function will get called as many times as the number of views bound to the controller.

Comment: Please add the code that calls loadCurrentUser() and explain where it is located. (e.g. inside of another controller, just in the view, or inside of a directive)

Comment: Yes Sa E Chowdary. I call only one time. Is strange because my website Is always calling 2 times each request for the console

Comment: Can you post your ngRoute configuration?

Comment: Try putting another `console.log`  underneath that one with just some static input maybe `"test"`.   This will help to determine if the call is being executed twice or if your endpoint is returning two `user`s

Comment: I suspect @AndreaM16 is correct, that your controller is being instantiated twice. Do you have multiple directives using the same controller in your template?

Comment: i just have directives for header and footer and each have one controller. Can be it?

Comment: what is handleSuccess???

Comment: is another function if u have success receive a message

Comment: thanks guys i resolve my problem...I have multiple views at the beginning of the project, I had never been very angular and I no longer remembered that